# How do I resolve "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'" when attempting to run pyspark on macOS

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark, homebrew

I have installed pyspark on macOS using brew but I'm getting the error when I type pyspark in zsh:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 86, in <module>
    print(_find_spark_home())
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 52, in _find_spark_home
    module_home = os.path.dirname(find_spec("pyspark").origin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'
```

I've tried setting the path inside the pyspark script but then got

```
/opt//homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: Permission denied
/opt//homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: exec: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I first had to locate and copy the apache spark directory to usr/local:

```
sudo cp -r /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark /usr/local/Cellar/
```

I found the spark directory with `sudo find /opt/ -name find_spark_home.py`
then I set the environment variables:

```
SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/bin:$PATH
```

after that typing pyspark gives:

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
23/01/23 13:31:11 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Reggies-MacBook-Pro.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.0.20 instead (on interface en0)
23/01/23 13:31:11 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/01/23 13:31:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022 12:41:40)
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.20:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1674498672860).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

Comment: If you wish to use pyspark with Jupyter, you may want also "export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'" and "export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks DrRaspberry that got me working.  I ended up just exporting the `SPARK_HOME` to `/opt/homebrew/opt/apache-spark/libexec` and ensuring I had `JAVA_HOME` defined and that seemed to work for me without having to copy binaries or be version specific.  Hopefully that will allow upgrades without having to revisit this each time.